# How to filter directories using the match-dir flag for pydocstyle?

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I would like to use [pydocstyle](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/index.html) as a [pre-commit hook](https://pre-commit.com/) to check a project's source code docstrings, i.e. .py files located inside the **/src** folder, when a new git commit is made. To check only the **src** folder, I used the [match-dir](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/usage.html#cli-usage) option, however, it appears to not work and there is an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle/issues/363).

Following the [pydocstyle documentation on pre-commit hook usage](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/usage.html#usage-with-the-pre-commit-git-hooks-framework), I added pydocstyle to the **.pre-commit-config.yaml** file, as follows:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pydocstyle
  rev: 5.1.1
  hooks:
  - id: pydocstyle
```

From here I tried two methods to configure the `match-dir` option: as a command line argument, and in a configuration file. To pass `match-dir` as a command line argument, I used the [args](https://pre-commit.com/#config-args) key in **.pre-commit-config.yaml** as follows:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pydocstyle
  rev: 5.1.1
  hooks:
  - id: pydocstyle
    args:
    - --match-dir='^(src)'
```

For the [configuration file](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/usage.html#configuration-files) method, I created a **.pydocstyle** file at the root of the project with the following contents:

```
[pydocstyle]
match_dir = ^(src)
```

Both methods appear to have no impact on the directories that are checked when pre-commit is run and pydocstyle checks all files in the project. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `pydocstyle --match-dir='^(src)'` from the command line — does it work at all? Try `pydocstyle` — does it take `match_dir` from `.pydocstyle`?

Comment: @phd I installed `pydocstyle` into the virtual environment using poetry: `poetry add pydocstyle`. This installed version 5.1.1, same as the version used by pre-commit. Both the command line argument and configuration file methods work and only check the **src** folder. This suggests that there is an issue with passing arguments to `pydocstyle` when used as a pre-commit hook. The example in the docs with the [ignore flag](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/stable/usage.html#usage-with-the-pre-commit-git-hooks-framework) works correctly. Therefore, I'm not sure why `match-dir` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-commit [passes filenames as positional arguments](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks) to hooks

Taking either of your attempts this means that it is calling it as:

```
pydocstyle --match-dir=^(src) file1.py file2.py src/file1.py src/file2.py
```

or

```
# with the configuration adjacent
pydocstyle file1.py file2.py src/file1.py src/file2.py
```

you'll notice that `pydocstyle` always runs files which are passed to it, independent of `--match-dir` (which is used when recursing only)

you can use `pre-commit`'s [`exclude`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-exclude) / [`files`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-files) to limit what is passed to the underlying tool:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pydocstyle
  rev: 5.1.1
  hooks:
  - id: pydocstyle
    files: ^src/
```

---

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit